# How to export Defects from HP QC to Excel using windows batch script?

Tags: hp-quality-center

Can someone tell me how to export Defects from HP QC to an Excel sheet using batch script?
I need an automation script to export HP QC defects to Excel using batch script or vb script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the QC addin directly from HPE main site or the business view tool for excel.

Two useful Add-in for Excel in order to get fast data from HP QC server are available under tools:
1) Access the Tools section on the server at https://QC-server_address/qcbin/

2) Choose the "more HP ALM add-ins"

3) Navigate to the Add-in and to add-in for Microsoft App as showed below.

4) Follow the steps showed by HP support in order to install the "Microsoft Excel add-in" or "the "Business View Microsoft Excel"

If you want to create some script then it will take a bit more time...but this is possible by the usage of QC REST API for instance. You can find a lot of already replied questions on SO.

Have a nice day! Ciao ciao

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try with these solutions.

Comment: Always welcome! Please close the question if the answer is correct. I wish you a nice day!